# Angular: how to find the data type of an Input property from a component in a external library

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular application that can be extended with external Angular (UMD) libraries at runtime, through including them with SystemJS. This works great, but I would like to be able to get more information about the components and their properties inside the external libraries.

When processing an Angular library, I compile the module inside the library

```
compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
```

and then iterator over the componentFactories.

Inside the ComponentFactory object, I get information about the component and it's inputs and outputs, but I don't know how to extract the data type information of these input and output properties-> is the property a boolean, or a string of of type Xyz? That information has to be in there somewhere, right (since my IDE seems to know this... hmm, but that is probably done through the .d.ts files in the library)?

I got to

```
factory.componentType.propDecorators['some-property-name'][0].type
```

which is of type `PropDecoratorFactory`.

Can I extract the actual ts Type of the property out of this `type:PropDecoratorFactory` some how?
Or in some other way out of the umd library?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use `Reflection` for this.

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab can you please elaborate on that? Do you have some example code?

Comment: sorry for late, search for 'reflect-metadata'